# Prevent PyCharm from opening stub files (*.pyi) instead of source files (*.py)

Tags: python, pycharm

When I ctrl+click a import name in PyCharm, it will often take me to the stub file instead of the source.

For example, following the `ssl` name in:

```
import ssl
```

Will take me to somewhere like:

```
~/pycharm/helpers/typeshed/stdlib/2and3/ssl.pyi
```

When I wanted to go instead to:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py
```

This is an intermittent but frequently reoccurring problem and I'm not sure what triggers it. I don't want to see the typeshed stubs. **How can you prevent PyCharm from preferring to open .pyi files instead of source files?**

Answer (score 4):

Should be fixed in 2019.3 EAP https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/

Relevant PyCharm issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35129

Comment: Still an issue in 2023: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54620/GoTo-declaration-jumps-to-pyi-stub-if-init.pyi-is-present

Comment: It was fixed, but I started seeing this again too now (on 2023.2). Seems the issue has regressed.

Comment: @wim Update to 2023.2.1 RC, there were a bunch of similar problems fixed (like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-61740).

Comment: Still an issue in 2023.3.2 for me, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54620/Go-To-Declaration-and-Go-To-Implementation-jump-to-pyi-stub-if-both-init.py-and-init.pyi-are-present#focus=Comments-27-8788206.0-0

Comment: @Blaise Caused by a different problem - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54946